# Separating Axis thereom: Calculating the MTV for Polygon & Line Segment

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, computational-geometry

I've been attempting, for months now, to write a function to return the minimum translation needed to be applied to a line segment in order to separate it from an polygon in which intersects. I'm using the separating axis theorem and it seems I'm able to calculate the magnitude correctly however, the direction returned is sometimes wrong. Yet, when the returned translation is incorrect, the inverse is always correct.

In the pictures below, the yellow line is the one used in calculations, the purple line is the yellow line + translation and the red line is the yellow line minus the translation. As you can see either the purple or the red line is correct in different positions but I'm not sure under what conditions to return which line.

[image: correct]
[image: incorrect]

So my question is: On what condition does the translation actually need to be flipped so that my function always returns a translation with the correct direction?

```
const Projection Polygon::Project(const Axis &a) const
{
    float min = a.Dot(GetPoint(0));
    float max = min;

    for (unsigned i = 1; i < GetPointCount(); i++)
    {
        float prj = a.Dot(GetPoint(i));

        if (prj < min)
            min = prj;

        else if (prj > max)
            max = prj;
    }

    return Projection(min, max);
}

const Projection Segment::Project(const Axis &a) const
{
    const float dot0 = a.Dot(GetPoint(0));
    const float dot1 = a.Dot(GetPoint(1));

    return Projection(std::min(dot0, dot1), std::max(dot0, dot1));
}

const float Projection::GetOverlap(const Projection &p) const
{
    // x = min & y = max
    return std::min(y - p.x, p.y - x);
}

const Vector2 Segment::GetTranslation(const Polygon &p) const
{
    float Overlap = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    Axis smallest;
    Vector2 translation;

    AxesVec axes(p.GetAxes());
    axes.push_back(GetAxis());

    for (auto && axis : axes)
    {
        const Projection pA = p.Project(axis);
        const Projection pB = Project(axis);

        if (pA.IsOverlap(pB))
        {
            const float o = pA.GetOverlap(pB);

            if (o < Overlap)
            {
                Overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;
            }
        }
    }

    translation = smallest * (Overlap + 1);

    return translation;
}
```

Comment: For images: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183932/297429. Please provide a link to the pictures and someone might edit the question.

Comment: For those who need it: [Separating Axis Theorem](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that your `GetOverlap` function returns the *magnitude* of the overlap, but not the *sense* (left or right).

You could change it to this:

```
if(y - p.x < p.y - x)
  return y - p.x;
else
  return x - p.y;
```

Then in `GetTranslation`:

```
const float o = pA.GetOverlap(pB);

if (abs(o) < abs(Overlap))
{
  ...
}

if (Overlap > 0)
  ++Overlap;
else
  --Overlap;

translation = smallest * Overlap;
```